# convert html into pdf using wkhtmltopdf in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Here is the thing. I have a html page having some content. I want to deploy a button so that using that i can make pdf of the contents of that page. i am using nodejs and want to make that pdf using wkhtmltopdf. I am new in web development. so a sample code or demonstration will be great help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf) module to convert HTML files or strings to PDFs. Call `whtmltopdf` function with either a URL or an inline HTML string, and it returns a stream that you can read from or pipe to wherever you like (e.g. a file, or an HTTP response).

Here is the step by step guide on Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop(64 bit).

1.Install the wkhtmltopdf command line tool on your system:

```
$ sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

2.Create the project directory `html2pdf` and install the `wkhtmltopdf` module:

```
$ mkdir html2pdf && cd html2pdf
$ npm install wkhtmltopdf
```

3.Edit the `app.js` file and input the following code:

```
var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
wkhtmltopdf('<h1>Test</h1><p>Hello world</p>', {output: 'out.pdf'});
```

4.Run the application and a PDF file named `out.pdf` will be created in the `html2pdf` directory.

```
$ node app.js
```

=============================================================================

For Windows:

1.Download [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) command line tool. Note: There are two versions of `wkhtmltopdf.exe`. One is for 32 bit Windows and the other is for 64 bit Windows.

2.Run the downloaded exe file and install wkhtmltopdf to specified directory, e.g., `c:\wkhtmltopdf`.

3.Create the project directory `html2pdf` and install the `wkhtmltopdf` module:

```
C:\> md html2pdf
C:\> cd html2pdf
C:\html2pdf> npm install wkhtmltopdf
```

4.Edit the `app.js` file and input the following code:

```
var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
wkhtmltopdf.command = 'c:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe';
wkhtmltopdf('<h1>Test</h1><p>Hello world</p>', {output: 'out.pdf'});
```

5.After running the application, a PDF file named `out.pdf` will be created in the `html2pdf` directory.

```
C:\html2pdf> node app.js
```

Comment: wkhtmltopdf.command = 'c:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe';
in that line it says that SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Have you installed 'wkhtmltopdf.exe' to `c:\wkhtmltopdf` directory?

Comment: no. actually i installed in program files and likewise i modified the path

Comment: How do I add options to wkhtmltopdf using the Windows solution?